# Pulldown list options aren't working

Tags: javascript, paypal

Please forgive this novice user! I am trying to create a table in which the user would select from a list of concert programs and then select a date (from among 2 or 3 associated dates) for the program selected. The same set of pulldown menus must be repeated 3 additional times. This is for a partial season subscription package in which a patron can select 4 out of 6 programs and the desired date for each program, and all that information needs to post to Paypal for processing/purchasing.

Please see this test page: http://early-music.org/Test_forTzN.html and this jsfiddle.net page: [jsfiddle.net/saraswati/v6Pur/31](http://jsfiddle.net/saraswati/v6Pur/31/)

As one can see on the webpage, my script works for "Concert 1," but not for Concerts 2, 3, and 4. On the jsfiddle page, even Concert 1 doesn't work.

Thank you for your help!

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var progamsAndDates = {};
        progamsAndDates['TUDORS'] = ['Sept. 15', 'Sept. 16'];
        progamsAndDates['NOCHES'] = ['Oct. 20', 'Oct. 21'];
        progamsAndDates['CHRISTMAS'] = ['Dec. 14', 'Dec. 15', 'Dec. 16'];
        progamsAndDates['CELTIC'] = ['Jan. 26', 'Jan. 27'];
        progamsAndDates['UNREQUITED'] = ['Mar. 02', 'Mar. 03'];
        progamsAndDates['SECRET'] = ['Apr. 20', 'Apr. 21'];

        function ChangeDateDropList (id) { 

            var programDropList = document.getElementById ("program"+id);
            var dateDropList = document.getElementById ("date"+id);
            var selProgram = programDropList.options[programDropList.selectedIndex].value;

            // remove all dates
            while (dateDropList.options.length) {
                dateDropList.remove (0);
            }

            // add new dates
            var dates = progamsAndDates[selProgram];
            if (dates) {
                for (var i=0; i < dates.length; i++) {
                    var date = new Option (dates[i], i);
                    dateDropList.options.add (date);
                }
            }
        } 
  </script>


<tr id=row2>
<td><input type="hidden" name="os0" value="Concert 1"><body onload="ChangeDateDropList ();">   
    <select id="program" onchange="ChangeDateDropList();"> 
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select a Program</option> 
        <option value="TUDORS">The Tudors</option> 
        <option value="NOCHES">Noches, Noches</option> 
        <option value="CHRISTMAS">Christmas Eurotour</option> 
        <option value="CELTIC">Celtic Trinity</option>
        <option value="UNREQUITED">Unrequited Love</option>
        <option value="SECRET">Secret No More</option> 
    </select> 

    <select id="date"> 
    </select> 
</body>
</td>

<td><input type="hidden" name="os1" value="Concert 2"><body onload="ChangeDateDropList ();">   
    <select id="program1" onchange="ChangeDateDropList(1);"> 
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select a Program</option> 
        <option value="TUDORS">The Tudors</option> 
        <option value="NOCHES">Noches, Noches</option> 
        <option value="CHRISTMAS">Christmas Eurotour</option> 
        <option value="CELTIC">Celtic Trinity</option>
        <option value="UNREQUITED">Unrequited Love</option>
        <option value="SECRET">Secret No More</option> 
    </select> 

    <select id="date1"> 
    </select>
</body> 
</td>

<td><input type="hidden" name="os2" value="Concert 3"><body onload="ChangeDateDropList ();">   
    <select id="program2" onchange="ChangeDateDropList(2);"> 
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select a Program</option> 
        <option value="TUDORS">The Tudors</option> 
        <option value="NOCHES">Noches, Noches</option> 
        <option value="CHRISTMAS">Christmas Eurotour</option> 
        <option value="CELTIC">Celtic Trinity</option>
        <option value="UNREQUITED">Unrequited Love</option>
        <option value="SECRET">Secret No More</option> 
    </select> 

    <select id="date2"> 
    </select> 
</body>
</td>

<td><input type="hidden" name="os3" value="Concert 4"><body onload="ChangeDateDropList ();">   
    <select id="program3" onchange="ChangeDateDropList(3);"> 
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select a Program</option> 
        <option value="TUDORS">The Tudors</option> 
        <option value="NOCHES">Noches, Noches</option> 
        <option value="CHRISTMAS">Christmas Eurotour</option> 
        <option value="CELTIC">Celtic Trinity</option>
        <option value="UNREQUITED">Unrequited Love</option>
        <option value="SECRET">Secret No More</option> 
    </select> 

    <select id="date3"> 
    </select> 
</body>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<center>
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
</center>
```

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle.net or similar instead of linking to your own page. This allows live testing.

Comment: all your selects have the same `select id="program"`. This is wrong, the id must be unique in a given `dom.document`. Your link doesn't work from here.

Comment: mr.VVoo: Apologies.  I just created a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/saraswati/v6Pur/

Comment: Sebas: Thank you for that critique. I'm not sure how to fix that, but I will try.

Comment: One more comment: It's odd that the selections work for Concert 1 on my test webpage, but it doesn't on the jsfiddle page. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of issues:

1. You have multiple "program" and "date" elements.  Each one of those needs its own unique ID so that you know which one you're referring to in your javascript.
2. Your ChangeDateDropList function expects 1 argument and you're not passing any.  (Note: This isn't incorrect syntax.  Just pointing it out since it appears were going down the correct route needing to pass an argument to your function but forgot to actually pass the argument in your function calls).

The simplest way to fix this is to rename each program and date element with a numerical suffix, ex: "program1", "date1", "program2", "date2", etc.  Once that's done you can pass the numerical suffix in to the ChangeDateDropList function and then use that to refer to the elements correctly:

```
function ChangeDateDropList (id) { 

        var programDropList = document.getElementById ("program"+id);
        var dateDropList = document.getElementById ("date"+id);
        ...
```

Don't forget to update your onchange calls also:

```
<select id="program1" onchange="ChangeDateDropList(1);">
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed analysis! Fingers crossed that I can fix this now. Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome.  If this answer solved your problem please select it as the correct answer by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.  (or you can wait and see what other answers are provided first)

Comment: Ok, I am too dense because I still can't get this to work. I did the changes you suggested, but I must still be missing something. :(

Comment: Thank you so very much for your help!  Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/saraswati/v6Pur/17/

Comment: You forgot to update the "date" names with the suffix, ex: <select id="date1"></select>

Comment: Again, thank you so much for taking the time to look at the code again. Actually, I tried adding the numbers to the "date" names, <select id="date1"></select>, and the script still doesn't work. :(

Comment: Your last jsfiddle is working - just change the second drop down box from "onLoad" to "No wrap - in <body>".

Comment: Apologies for the long previous comment. Here's the link to the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/saraswati/v6Pur/57/ Thank you so much for your time and patience!

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance!  I see now what you meant about the 2nd drop down box in jsfiddle; it's under the "Framework & Extensions." I've selected "No wrap - in <body>" and OMG! It works in jsfiddle now! I tried it also on my test webpage and it works there, too. I can't thank you enough! I am one step closer to implementing. Now I have another issue to work out: Paypal is not picking up the choices of programs and dates when the user clicks on the Paypal button. I will query the wisdom in the Paypal area. I THANK YOU SO MUCH for all your help and patience!!! Cheers!